# 405 (Method Not Allowed) Axios - Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, post, axios

I'm trying to create a form where the user fills in some data and after that the data is submited to the server

```
 methods: {
    sendOrder () {
        this.loading = true;
        axios.post ('/send/', {
           firstName: this.firstName,
           lastName: this.lastName,
           phone: this.phone,
           delivery: this.delivery,
           ... (this.delivery? {address: this.address}: {}),
           note: this.note,
           items: this.items,
           total: this.total

        })
```

this works great on my local server, however when i set up on the real server i get the following error in the console:

`http://my-website.com/email-sender/public/send 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

I doubt this part of the response where you can see ...`email-sender/public`...

Is this possible due to the wrong .htaccess setting?

Also, when I make a post request to this same route via postman I get this error:

`Status: 419 unknown status`

it doesn't matter if i send the request to `http://my-webiste.com/send` or

`http://my-webiste.com/public/email-sender/send` the error on postman is allways `419`.

Routes (from comment):

```
Route::get('/', 'OrderController@index');
Route::get('/thankyou', 'OrderController@thankyou');
Route::post('/send', 'OrderController@send');
```

Comment: Show your routes please.

Comment: Route::get('/', 'OrderController@index');

Route::get('/thankyou', 'OrderController@thankyou');

Route::post('/send', 'OrderController@send');

Comment: `/send/` and `/send` might be different urls. Also, the `public` folder in Laravel should be the "DocumentRoot" of your project/server and not appear in your urls

Comment: I changed the routes to `/send` on both axios method and in  `web.php` but still the same error. I dont know why the project root is apearing in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Specifically, the problem was in the .htaccess file, which did not point well to the public root of the Laravel application.

Previously, I had a public folder and a Laravel project folder in it, which I had to change in order for all Laravel files to be in that root folder.

Now the problem with displaying the entire path in the url disappeared as well as the problem with code 419. I hope I explained the solution to the problem properly.